# yii objects and object fields

Tags: object, yii, field

I'm not sure how to put this right.

I need to use yii to create an application which needs to use objects and fields.

Let's say that in my app I want to have those three objects: Computers, Servers, IPs. Each of these three objects will have it's own attributes:
Computer: CPU, Motherboard, Video adapter, IP (related to the object IP), Aquisition Date
Servers: Name, IP (related to object IP), etc...
IP: IP Address.
As you can see I also need a way to link my objects between them.
Every kind of attribute (object field) must be treated in it's own way, after it's own type. For example, we have a field called CPU which can be in a list of values. We have Aquisition Date and it must be treated like a date.

Well, the problem is that I need an extension to help me in creating those object types and setting their attributes. I don't know how to search for something appropriate.

Implementing this functionalities will take me a lot of time which I don't have right now. If there are no extensions, do you have any solution to implement one? I have some ideas for creating classes for every user field, classes which will implement an interface that render the methods properly for insert, update, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extension if you use Yii. You'd rather yake some time to read the [tutorials](http://www.yiiframework.com/tutorials/). My advice is to begin with [Larry Ullman's Learning Yii Series](http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/) and then to go to the [Definitive Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/)

Once you have set your database and build your tables, you will only have to activate the [**Gii**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app#implementing-crud-operations) component of Yii framework and to use it's automated code generators to build your basic models, views and controllers.

The only thing you've left will be customization, of course. Yii + Gii save you all the repetitive work. But... read the docs.

**[EDIT]** after the OP comment below.

Is it an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) that you are looking for ? There is an unofficial Yii extension dealing with that : [EAV Behavior](http://yiiext.github.io/extensions/eav-behavior/). I have no idea whether it's good or not, as I definitely avoid to work with EAV databases. Let us know your opinion if you try to use it.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I know those tutorials, I think got over them. Your answer is not working in my case because I have to create a table for any object that I create. I am trying to avoid this and have only or or two tables, one that stores the data of the input and the other one the definition of that input.